# Concatenating a string with a range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, range, string-concatenation

```py
x= ("bonus")
i=[str(i) for i in range(80,121)]
for s in i:
    z=x+s
```

I am trying to get an outcome of

```
bonus80
bonus81
bonus82
...
..
bonus120
```

So I could use the outcome for below code

```py
bonus_80=df["Bonus Payout 80%"].values
bonus_81=df["Bonus Payout 81%"].values
# ...
bonus_119=df["Bonus Payout 119%"].values
bonus_120=df["Bonus Payout 120%"].values
```

But still could not find a way to do it, I tried many variations to no end.

Comment: ["bonus" + str(i) for i in range(80, 120)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is to dynamically create variables. As @JarroVGIT mentionned, using a dictionary is better. But otherwise you can access the `globals()` dictionary to access variable names :

```py
for i in range(80, 121):
    globals()[f"bonus_{i}"] = df[f"Bonus Payout {i}%"].values
```

Then you have your 20 independant variables and you can access them like any other.

```
bonus_110 = 110
print(bonus_84)
```

Comment: thanks a lot this was the issue i was facing

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dictionary for dynamic key/value pairs.

```
result = {}
for i in range (80,121):
    result[f"Bonus_{i}"] = df[f"Bonus Payout {i}%"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x= ("bonus")
i=[str(i) for i in range(80,121)]
for s in i:
    z=x+s
```

I would tell you *"Nice try"*, but have you noticed that you're not printing anything?

---

I would do this:

```
l = [f"Bonus Payout {i}%" for i in range(80, 120)]
```

and then, if you want to access that `df`:

```
n = [df[key] for key in l]
```